# What do I need to know in the 1st day of my new job?

Tags: new-job

I am going to start my new job (an engineer position) in a 25 people company tomorrow. I am thinking to write down a list of something that must be told by others, so that I can ask all those questions in one time and I don't have to brother people many times.

For example,

where is my desk

what is the computer password

how I can set up an email account

Comment: This won't be an issue, just go to work.  Good luck

Answer (score 6):

Unless your company has a ridiculously poor onboarding process, the obvious questions should already be taken care of.  Someone will undoubtedly meet you on your first day and will show you to your desk, give you some paperwork to fill out for taxes and benefits, give you information about accessing the systems, and whatever else the company needs to give you.

Realistically, the questions you're going to need to ask are things that the company failed to think about when putting together the onboarding process.  It is unlikely that these are things you are going to think of in advance because they are invariably very specific to the organization and to the role.  If you are a software developer, for example, there is a decent chance the the documentation on how to configure your development environment won't be 100% clear and you'll need to ask someone to clarify or that an account hasn't been set up in some system that you need to access yet.

Comment: indeed. If such documentation exists at all. One job I had to wait a week for a computer, then another week or more for a network account, etc. etc. Another job we brought in 10 guys who had to wait a month before they even had desks and chairs to sit on (they spent the month playing cards on the floor in the hallways, don't you love bureaucracies).

Comment: I think most companies have terrible onboarding processes, though.